# Laravel - Passar mais de um parâmetro usando o use em funções de callback?

Tags: php, laravel-5

É o seguinte, tenho uma função de `callback` desse tipo:

```
\Excel::create($limite_vagas_array[0]['nome_curso']
          .' - '.$limite_vagas_array[0]['nome_polo']
          .' - Limite de vagas', function($excel) use ($limite_vagas_array)
        {
            $excel->sheet('sheet', function($sheet) use ($limite_vagas_array)
           {
                //#code
           }
        });
```

No `use` chamo o array `$limite_vagas_array`, no entanto gostaria de passar mais um `array`.

Como faço isso?

Comment: A sua pergunta está sem sentido, você pode passar quantos você quiser? qual a dificuldade?

Comment: Eu queria passar outro array. Tipo use ($limite_vagas_array, $outro_array)... Tentei fazer isso mas não deu certo. Qual é a sintaxe?

Comment: Consegui mano. Valeu

Comment: Você poderia colocar a sua própria resposta, @Fellipe!